# CloudFormation UpdateStack

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a stack that is initially created from a CloudFormation template. I need to add some dynamic tags in node.js when I save a file to my s3 bucket. This is my code.

```
let date = new Date();
let currentDate = date.toISOString();

let cloudFormationParams = {
    StackName: 'name-of-stack-created-from-cloud-formation', 
    Tags: [
      {
        Key: 'CurrentDate',
        Value: currentDate
      },
      /* more items */
    ],
    UsePreviousTemplate: true 
  };

  await cloudformation.updateStack(cloudFormationParams, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        return { status: "error" }
    } else {
        console.log(data);           // successful response

    }
}).promise();
```

This gives me the error "ValidationError","errorMessage":"Stack: is in UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS state and can not be updated.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this error just means that your stack is currently in the process of being updated.... wait until your stack is in a final state (ending in COMPLETE or FAILED) and try again

Comment: To expand on the problem, I am trying to call a function to save each file in a for loop. This function contains the code to update the stack. The tag gets added correctly for the first file in the loop, but all files after that generate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs provides [wait_for](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#waitFor-property) method that allows you to **wait in your code** for the stack being in the state if interest. The possible states you can wait for are:

- stackExists
- stackCreateComplete
- stackUpdateComplete
- and more.

Thus you can add `wait_for` with `stackUpdateComplete` to your code before you perform further actions on the stack.